# JSONRepresentation showing error

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, json, ipad

i have some data in dictionary like

```
 NSMutableDictionary *jsonDictionary;
 jsonDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
 [jsonDictionary setValue:@"XYZ" forKey:@"CommandType"];
 [jsonDictionary setValue:@"ABC" forKey:@"AppID"];
 [jsonDictionary setValue:@"PQM" forKey:@"UserName"];

 NSURLResponse *response;
 NSError *error;

 NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:jsonDictionary options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&error];

 NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:
                                [NSURL URLWithString:@"Http://SomeURL"]];

[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setHTTPBody: jsonData];

[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [jsonData length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];

NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
NSString *serverResponse = (NSString *)[[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSMutableDictionary *results = [serverResponse JSONValue];
```

In my "results" i am geting null.. what is problem in it and showing me error's in consol.
Error's are as follows.

```
 -JSONRepresentation failed. Error trace is: (
"Error Domain=org.brautaset.JSON.ErrorDomain Code=4 \"Not valid type for JSON\" UserInfo=0x6b8d880 {NSLocalizedDescription=Not valid type for JSON}"

 -JSONFragment failed. Error trace is: (
"Error Domain=org.brautaset.JSON.ErrorDomain Code=1 \"JSON serialisation not supported for NSMutableURLRequest\" UserInfo=0x6b8ddf0 {NSLocalizedDescription=JSON serialisation not supported for NSMutableURLRequest}"
```

can any help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 2):

Try using `NSJSONSerialization` to perform the translation back to JSON:

```
NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
id result = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:0 error:&error];
```

In case this doesn't work, I'm pretty sure it's because your server is returning empty responses. I tried sending the following request:

> Accept: */*
>       Content-Type: application/json
>       Content-Length: 65
>       Accept-Language: en-us
>       Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
>
> {
>         "AppID": "ABC",
>         "CommandType": "XYZ",
>         "UserName": "PQM"
>       }

And I got back the following response header (with no body):

> HTTP/1.1 200 OK
>
> Date: Wed, 30 Jan 2013 14:58:43 GMT
>       X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
>       Content-Length: 0
>       X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
>       Cache-Control: private
>       Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5

Content length is 0.

Comment: thnx for you quick replay. but this is not working for me.. have you any other suggestion for how can i solve this issue.

Comment: Did you check the raw data coming back from the server? Maybe the JSON string is corrupt.

Comment: i checked on browser and on browser all is right.  i check in json checker there are also every thing is all right.

Comment: Can you post the path to the resource?

Comment: Just made a test call to this endpoint and got a response with an empty body. I added all of the fields as shown in your code.

Comment: thnx for ur help. i just alloc NSMutableURLRequest and in request object i add this        [request addValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request addValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",postBody.length] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];    then my problem is solve..

Answer (score 0):

This line

```
[request setHTTPBody: temp];
```

should be

```
[request setHTTPBody: jsonData];
```

Comment: bu mistak i type that sorry.. i edited my question my problem is still same.

Answer (score -1):

I think, It's helpful to you.so you can try this following Code.NSJSON Serialization method.and try this link[NSJSON Serialization JSON](http://sonnyparlin.com/2012/04/parsing-json-with-ios-5/)

```
NSError *error = nil;
NSData *jsonData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://192.168.1.37:3333/UniECommerce/api/store-list.html"]];

    if (jsonData) 
    {
        id jsonObjects = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];

        if (error) 
        {
            NSLog(@"error is %@", [error localizedDescription]);

            // Handle Error and return
            return;
        }

        //NSArray *keys = [jsonObjects allKeys];
        NSArray *keys=[[jsonObjects objectForKey:@"storelist"]valueForKey:@"store_list"];
        // values in foreach loop
        for (NSDictionary *key in keys)// here used to array type key 
        {
            // NSLog(@"%@ is %@",key, [jsonObjects objectForKey:key]);

            if ([key valueForKey:@"store_image"]!=[NSNull null])
            {

              [imageUrls  addObject:[key objectForKey:@"store_image"]];
               // imageUrls [key valueForKey:@"store_image"];
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thnx for your replay but i want to post data to the server.. i have problem in sending data to server.